# How to use PBKDF2 in java to get the same result as c#?

Tags: java, c#, hash, pbkdf2

I want to convert my c# codes to java with PBKDF2 hashing and with the same result(no real product, just test).

C#:

```
static string Pbkdf2Hashing(string password)
    {
        byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
        string hashed = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
            password: password,
            salt: salt,
            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA1,
            iterationCount: 10000,
            numBytesRequested: 256 / 8));
        return hashed;
    }
```

The result:

1. List item

   oudaCubzWVIMjTxaQh1KT85fn+p2KjQRdBDXpiS8AUA=

Java:

```
 static String Pbkdf2Hashing(String password) throws Exception {
    byte[] salt = new byte[128 / 8];
    int iterations = 10000;
    int derivedKeyLength = 256;
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, derivedKeyLength);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    byte[] result = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result);
}
```

The result:

```
dxtD2eQ/4Sj5pGnPqCTiuL6jns5apO1OHkTaJC9DTzw=
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So that the Java code gives the same result as the C# code, simply replace *PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256* with *PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1* in the Java code.

Since you didn't post the plaintext to your example, I use for my test the plaintext

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

for which the C# Code and the *fixed* Java Code both return

```
mPfEIpaydCQU15ACyPW+jPh/ctqi8q74aWhO9nWz9Q0=
```

as result.